# Call by reference, Functional prototype in C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

The following program should read a double number x and an int number and output their value on the screen. The readin function () is used for reading. I have marked missing points where I have problems in the program with (.......). I added comments of how I tried it but it still hasnt worked. May someone please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
void readin(double*, int*);

int main(void) {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    double x;
    int n;
    readin(.......); //readin(&x, &n);
    printf("\nd are %6.2lf", x);
    printf("\nn are %6i", n);
    return 0;
}
void readin(double* x, int* n) {
    printf("\nEnter a double value for x: ");
    scanf(.....); //scanf("%f", &n);
    printf("\nEnter an int value for n: ");
    scanf(.....);   //scanf("%f", &x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `readin()` correctly, but not `scanf()`. The arguments to `scanf()` should be pointers to where you want the values stored. Since `x` and `n` are already pointers, you don't need to take their addresses.

You also had `x` and `n` swapped in the `scanf()` calls. And the format operators should be `%lf` for `double` and `%d` for `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void readin(double*, int*);

int main(void) {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    double x;
    int n;
    readin(&x, &n);
    printf("\nd are %6.2lf", x);
    printf("\nn are %6i", n);
    return 0;
}
void readin(double* x, int* n) {
    printf("\nEnter a double value for x: ");
    scanf("%lf", x);
    printf("\nEnter an int value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", n);
}
```